# How to install gitolite?

Tags: installation, gitolite

#### How to install gitolitev3 in ubuntu 14.04 and once installation done how to verify?

Description:

Already tried with sudo apt-get install gitolite command but now sure is it installed. How to verify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way is to [follow the doc](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html):

```
su - git
mkdir -p ~/bin

git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
gitolite/install -ln ~/bin          # please use absolute path here
gitolite setup -pk yourname.pub
```

By cloning the [gitolite repo](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), you ensure to install the very latest version of gitolite  (3.6.1+)

Comment: @Abhishek don't forget to add your `~/bin` to your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly choose the gitolite3 package:

```
sudo apt-get install gitolite3
```

The gitolite package will install the version 2.
If you can clone the admin repository then the installation is ok.